# Define relation from table with link tables primary key using Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Hi i am trying to work out how in eloquent you can define this relationship: 
[Image Of Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB3Jj.png)

I used belongs to many to link the manufacturers and equipment types together eg:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\EquipmentType','equipment_types_manufacturers', 
      'manufacturer_id', 'equipment_type_id');
```

But trying to define the relationship i can't find how you can define the link from the equipment_model FK etml_id -> equipment_types_manufacturers PK

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EquipmentType','equipment_types_manufacturers', 
      'equipment_types_manufacturers_id', 'equipment_type_id');
```

Which in sql fails

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'manufacturers.equipment_types_manufacturers_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `equipment_models` where exists (select * from `manufacturers` where `equipment_models`.`equipment_types_manufacturers_id` = `manufacturers`.`equipment_types_manufacturers_id` and `manufacturer_id` = 1) and exists (select * from `equipment_types` where `equipment_models`.`equipment_types_manufacturers_id` = `equipment_types`.`equipment_types_manufacturers_id` and `equipment_type_id` = 1))

I feel this can be achieved by creating a model for the link table but i'm not sure that that is correct?

Comment: Update: I am now trying to query using this 

        $models = EquipmentModel::has('equipmentTypesManufacturer.manufacturer')->with(
            [
            'equipmentTypesManufacturer' => function ($query) {
                $query->where([['manufacturer_id', 5],['equipment_type_id',5]]);
            },
            'equipmentTypesManufacturer.manufacturer',
            'equipmentTypesManufacturer.equipmentType'])->get();
        
This will work but you will always get the top level model ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a model via another model/table. You need to use `hasManyThrough()`. In your Manufacturer model, try

```
public function equipments() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'EquipmentModel', 'EquipmentTypesManufacturer',
        'manufacturer_id', 'etml_id', 'id'
    );
}
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Do you have to create a model for each link table that you wish to use then ?

Comment: Yes you will have to. That's how hasManyThrough works

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, however this method doesn't achieve what i need. There seems to be no way to specify they key to join the EquipmentModel to the link table so it is always looking for an entry EquipmentModel.id -> EquipmentTypesManufacturer.id ?